# How do I print this collection in a formatted way?

Tags: laravel

I have stored a cart in the database and want to associate it with an order number so that I can view order items. I have stored the cart using `Cart::store($identifier)` and retrived using `$d = DB::table('shoppingcart')->get();`. How do I print out this content?

I have tried using foreach loop but is not helping

```
+"content": "O:29:"Illuminate\Support\Collection":1:{s:8:"\x00*\x00items";a:2:{s:32:"07cca15168b1a5e48e0f89d878fbf6ea";O:32:"Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem":9:{s:5:"rowId";s:32:"07cca15168b1a5e48e0f89d878fbf6ea";s:2:"id";s:2:"16";s:3:"qty";i:1;s:4:"name";s:19:"Dr. Granville Braun";s:5:"price";d:515;s:7:"options";O:39:"Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItemOptions":1:{s:8:"\x00*\x00items";a:0:{}}s:49:"\x00Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem\x00associatedModel";s:11:"App\Product";s:41:"\x00Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem\x00taxRate";i:21;s:41:"\x00Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem\x00isSaved";b:0;}s:32:"027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da";O:32:"Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem":9:{s:5:"rowId";s:32:"027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da";s:2:"id";s:1:"1";s:3:"qty";i:1;s:4:"name";s:17:"Double Wall Glass";s:5:"price";d:547;s:7:"options";O:39:"Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItemOptions":1:{s:8:"\x00*\x00items";a:0:{}}s:49:"\x00Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem\x00associatedModel";s:11:"App\Product";s:41:"\x00Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem\x00taxRate";i:21;s:41:"\x00Gloudemans\Shoppingcart\CartItem\x00isSaved";b:0;}}} ◀"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data in the array format like this :

```
$d = DB::table('shoppingcart')->get()->toArray();
```